# How to enable credit card payment option in the "select your payment method" window?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using the PayPal PHP SDK. I cannot enable the credit card payment option. Here are the relevant parts of my code and screenshots from the PayPal payment pages.

I set up my test merchant account and upgraded to pro. The test buyer account has a credit card attached to their acccount.

What can I do?

---

Screenshot 1

[image]

---

Screenshot 2

[image]

---

Screenshot 3

[image]

---

Relevant code

```
$payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

    // Specify the payment amount.
    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency($currency);
    $amount->setTotal($total);

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount);
    $transaction->setDescription($paymentDesc);

    $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl($returnUrl);
    $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl);

    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
    $payment->setIntent("sale");
    $payment->setPayer($payer);
    $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    $payment->create($this->getApiContext());
```